# Adding Apache common dependency to Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

i want to import org.apache.commons.io but i'm getting this error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /home/ghost/Bureau/app/play-2.0.1/waf/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[error] /home/ghost/Bureau/app/play-2.0.1/waf/app/controllers/Application.java:9: error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
[error]     import org.apache.commons.io.*;
[error]     ^
[error] /home/ghost/Bureau/app/play-2.0.1/waf/app/controllers/Application.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
[error]                 FileUtils.copyFile(file, destinationFile);
[error]                 ^
[error]   symbol:   variable FileUtils
[error]   location: class Application
[error] 2 errors
[error] {file:/home/ghost/Bureau/app/play-2.0.1/waf/}waf/compile:compile: javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application -
```

Play can't find package org.apache.commons.io .
How can i add apache io as a dependency ?

Comment: put the jar in the classpath and import it in your class

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To add the dependencies

1. Edit project Build.scala file : `/project/Build.scala` and add dependency for `commons-io`

   ```
   val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
     "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"
   )
   ```
2. using play console check dependency resolved or not use command: `play dependencies`

Tip: If you're not familiar with SBT syntax mvnrepository.com allows you to copy proper one in `SBT` tab: [commons-io sample](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.3)