# What Mailer for Play Framework 2.2?

Tags: java, playframework, mailer, playframework-2.2

Someone could reccomend me **what mailer** install on the new **Play 2.2.1 (java)**? And **how to install**?

From older questions I've seen that the [TypeSafe](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer) one is developed by Play creators that it should be good about compatibility but it doesn't send email with attachments, and they don't specify the dependencies to use on Play 2.2. Another suggestion I found is [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/index.html) mail (this seems to send also attachments), but don't know if works on 2.2 and how to install it. I'm finding lack of documentation on this side.

I'd like a lightweight Mailer that doesn't install tons of library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to install:

For unmanaged dependency just download the binaries, unzip it and copy the required ***.jar** files into **lib** folder in your project (create it if doesn't exists).

Optionally if you can find required package in Maven repository, you can just add a managed dependency to your build file (in SBT format).

Both approaches are clearly described in the [Play's dependencies doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies).

Just tip: after adding dependencies, clean the build, update dependencies and [re-create configuration for your prefered IDE](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE) if required.

**Edit:**

Here you've got all Apache's commons in Maven: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons

Just go to last version of required lib and copy required dependency format (from SBT tab in this case) and use as described in above docs.

FYI: Play already imports some commons libraries ie. `lang3`, others like `io`, `email` etc you can import additionally if required.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation on how to install dependencies. But I was asking **what mailer** to install on Play 2.2.1 and how.

Comment: Ahah yes, I appreciate your answer on the "how" part. Apache was the solution that I was looking for. My problem is that on the site there isn't the **string** (and **latest version**) to add in `build.sbt` file. Where can I find it? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11167112/1252920) but don't know if it's correct for play 2.2.1

Comment: Ops, is it [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io)? In that page I can see the latest version (2.4 now). Open that page and click on SBT tab for the string. Then I paste it in sbt file on play. Am I right? Another question: I read that Commons IO are "_utility classes, stream implementations, file filters, file comparators, endian transformation classes, and much more_". I wouldn't want that it install a tons of library that I will not use.

Comment: Awesome! Then, for install **only** Apache `commons-email` (latest version) on SBT I need to paste in `build.sbt` this string: `"org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.1"`. Thanks a lot biesior!